# Select Consecutive Association rows based on pattern

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering, associations

I have an association that I have already sorted on `"EVDATE"` and then grouped by some Keys.  In this case `"CONTID"` and `"OZONE"`

A subset of the result is something like this:

```
data={
 <|"CONTID" -> 47001805, "EVDATE" -> {2017, 1, 1, 0, 4, 37.}, "OZONE" -> 50, "EVTYPE" -> 1, "ZONE" -> 50, "KEYALM" -> "E150"|>, 
 <|"CONTID" -> 47001805, "EVDATE" -> {2017, 1, 1, 0, 18, 53.997}, "OZONE" -> 50, "EVTYPE" -> 0, "ZONE" -> 50, "KEYALM" -> "R150"|>, 
 <|"CONTID" -> 47001805, "EVDATE" -> {2017, 1, 28, 14, 26, 53.}, "OZONE" -> 50, "EVTYPE" -> 1, "ZONE" -> 50, "KEYALM" -> "E150"|>, 
 <|"CONTID" -> 47001805, "EVDATE" -> {2017, 1, 28, 14, 51, 51.}, "OZONE" -> 50, "EVTYPE" -> 0, "ZONE" -> 50, "KEYALM" -> "R150"|>
}
```

I would like to regroup, partition, or select the rows that form pairs of consecutive row values of `"KEYALM"` that equal `"E150"` and `"R150"` respectively, in that order no gaps, as many as there are in the subset, etc.

Only those that match the pattern of consecutive rows.  There are some instances were the pairs are not balanced or there are two `"E150"s` in a row and that is why selecting only the pairs of `"E150"`, `"R150"` consecutively interest me.

I have tried,

```
Cases[data, {___, #1[["KEYALM"]] == "E150", #2[["KEYALM"]] == "R150", __} &]
```

as well as,

```
SequenceCases[data, {#1[["KEYALM"]] == "E150", #2[["KEYALM"]] == "R150"} &]
```

as well as,

```
Gather[data, #1[["KEYALM"]] == "E150" === #2[["KEYALM"]] == "R150" &]
```

`Gather` gets close but isn't correct.

the correct answer should be:

```
res={
 {
   <|"CONTID" -> 47001805, "EVDATE" -> {2017, 1, 1, 0, 4, 37.`}, "OZONE" -> 50, "EVTYPE" -> 1, "ZONE" -> 50, "KEYALM" -> "E150"|>, 
   <|"CONTID" -> 47001805, "EVDATE" -> {2017, 1, 1, 0, 18, 53.997`}, "OZONE" -> 50, "EVTYPE" -> 0, "ZONE" -> 50, "KEYALM" -> "R150"|>
 }, {
   <|"CONTID" -> 47001805, "EVDATE" -> {2017, 1, 28, 14, 26, 53.`}, "OZONE" -> 50, "EVTYPE" -> 1, "ZONE" -> 50, "KEYALM" -> "E150"|>, 
   <|"CONTID" -> 47001805, "EVDATE" -> {2017, 1, 28, 14, 51, 51.`}, "OZONE" -> 50, "EVTYPE" -> 0, "ZONE" -> 50, "KEYALM" -> "R150"|>
}}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a bit brute force, but it works:

```
Select[  Partition[data, 2,  1] , #[[All, "KEYALM"]] == {"E150", "R150"} & ]
```

Comment: `Partition[..,2,1]` looks at every pair.  This is probably slow though if its a big list.

Comment: Correct, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

I thought this will work:

```
SequenceCases[
 data,
 KeyValuePattern /@ {"KEYALM" -> "E150", "KEYALM" -> "R150"}
]
```

but it didn't (why?), so here is a workaround

```
data[[#]] & /@ SequencePosition[
    data[[All, "KEYALM"]]
  , {"E150", "R150"}
]
```

Comment: this does it `SequenceCases[data, {a_ /; a[["KEYALM"]] == "E150", 
  b_ /; b[["KEYALM"]] == "R150"}]`

Comment: @george2079 yep. any idea why `KeyValuePattern` fails?

Comment: Maybe it needs an `Evaluate`  ( I don't have `KeyValuePattern` in 10.1 to try )

Comment: @george2079 I don't think so, will try to investigate later. Thanks for additional example.

Comment: I like SequenceCases[data, {a_ /; a[["KEYALM"]] == "E150", b_ /; b[["KEYALM"]] == "R150"}] as the answer.  So which one should I select as the answer.  I will let @george2079 and Kuba decide.  Thank you for the help.